# Textarea that grows and shrinks with content to a maximum height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

First of all, I know that similar questions to this have been asked here, although none of them specifically do what my title asks for.

I am trying to create a simple textarea input that grows and shrinks in height according to its content, but to a maximum height only. Once the maximum height has been met, it will scroll vertically.

I came across a pure CSS and HTML solution, although unfortunately it is not cross browser, and could be quite buggy. But it should give you all a good idea of what I am trying to achieve.

**HTML:**

```
<div contenteditable>
    type here...
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div[contenteditable] {
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vz7awr2f/)**

Is there a solution, that does not use `contenteditable`, that can replicate the above example using only a text input or textarea?

Comment: try http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a solution to the same problem, and realized that using the elastic javascript solution seemed to be the best all-around solution. Tested in in all modern browsers, including back to IE9:

View working demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mupbrtpv/

Use a max-height of your choice on the textarea to prevent the height from expanding beyond your desired limit.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="description" placeholder="input your text here"></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
textarea#description{width: 300px; max-height: 400px;}
```

Javscript:

```
$('#description').elastic();
```

Comment: Works well. Although, it always seems to have an extra line underneath the line that is being currently typed on. Is there a way to remove this?

Comment: @fizzix I'm not too familiar with exactly how it works, except it appears that extra line does get used for a fraction of second after you hit enter, or create a new line of text in the textarea. But it does appear that after a second, it then creates a "new" blank line again -- probably to help cue the user that the box has more space available. I don't know how to undo that.